# sed back-reference not working

Tags: sed

I need to process every line of a curve CSV to remove the last column of only those lines which start with 10 commas. the sed command I used was:

```
$ cat curves.csv
(...)
,,,,,,,,,,2017/10/18,20630.000000
,,,,,,,,,,2017/11/15,20595.000000
,usdSN,:usdSN,,,,8005,$,,2017/08/07,Settlement Date
,,,,,,,,,,2017/12/20,20575.000000
,,,,,,,,,,2018/01/17,20555.000000
,,,,,,,,,,2018/02/21,20535.000000
(...)
,,,,,,,,,,2018/12/21,20290.000000
,usdZS,:usdZS,,,,8007,$,,2017/08/07,Settlement Date
,,,,,,,,,,2017/08/16,2848.500000
(...)

$ sed  s/\(,,,,,,,,,,[0-9/]*\),[0-9.]*/\1/g  curves.csv
```

however, it didn't work. it printed out all lines unchanged.

Please help.

Comment: sed  s/\(,,,,,,,,,,[0-9/]*\),[0-9.]*/\1/g  curves.csv                <-----not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you are running sed.  You did:

```
sed  s/\(,,,,,,,,,,[0-9/]*\),[0-9.]*/\1/g  curves.csv
```

But because the parameters aren't quoted the shell resolves the escape characters and what is actually run is:

```
sed  s/(,,,,,,,,,,[0-9/]*),[0-9.]*/\1/g  curves.csv
```

Which doesn't match anything because there are no parenthesis in your file.  How you should run it is:

```
sed 's/\(,,,,,,,,,,[0-9/]*\),[0-9.]*/\1/g' curves.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with GNU sed:

```
sed -r '/^,{10}/{s/,[^,]*$//}' file
```

Output:

```
(...)
,,,,,,,,,,2017/10/18
,,,,,,,,,,2017/11/15
,usdSN,:usdSN,,,,8005,$,,2017/08/07,Settlement Date
,,,,,,,,,,2017/12/20
,,,,,,,,,,2018/01/17
,,,,,,,,,,2018/02/21
(...)
,,,,,,,,,,2018/12/21
,usdZS,:usdZS,,,,8007,$,,2017/08/07,Settlement Date
,,,,,,,,,,2017/08/16
(...)
```

Comment: Elegant solution.